# Crystal Reports blank page "standard" solution not working

Tags: crystal-reports

Having an annoying problem with a report. It's a fairly simple report with 1 group and multiple detail sections (each detail section contains a subreport).
Sometimes the data makes the groupfooter start just on the next page, printing an empty page with just the groupheader and pagefooter.
The "standard" solution of adding Not OnLastRecord formula in the groupfooters New Page After option doesn't work. 
I've been trying with Suppress, Hide, Keep Together options all over the report, but nothing seems to work.
Anybody have other suggestions?

I'm using Crystal Report in Visual Studio (not the stand alone)

Answer (score 0):

**What is the result you want to achieve?**
The content doesn't fit the page, I suppose.
`GroupHeader + Content + GroupFooter` can't be printed in a single page, so there's a page with just GroupHeader or one with GroupFooter only.

**If you want to divide subreport between pages**
I suppose that you have to look at Details Section, removing Keep Together clause to Details, to SubReport and inside SubReport so that details section will be divided, if possible, in the page with GroupHeader and in the page with GroupFooter

**If you want GroupHeader and GroupFooter to be printed on any page, also if Subereport doesn't fit**
GroupHeader can be repeated on every page ("repeat group footer on each page" in Group Expert), GroupFooter can't.. someone suggest to use Page Footer instead.

Comment: It's the 3th option I'm after. The GroupHeader is already repeated on every page. Detail sections are nowhere kept together.
Grouping is done by an ID. The GroupFooter just ends up on a new page. So when I have the GroupFooter set at a Height of 1, it looks like a blank page with GroupHeader and PageFooter (GroupFooter is empty, I'm not confusing PageFooter with GroupFooter here)
When I suppress the GroupFooter, the GroupHedeader still get's printed immediatly followed by the next ID's GroupHeader (on the same page, which is even worse looking then a blank page).

Comment: So, since you need GroupHeader and GroupFooter to be printed on any page, can you try moving all elements from GroupHeader and GroupFooter to PageHeader and PageFooter? What happens?

Comment: I can't. PageHeader contains the title, PageFooter contains printdate etc..
GroupHeader contains Id, name, etc. in a subreport, first page of the group has all info, where part of the subreport is suppressed on subsequent pages with a formula (parameter)
    WhilePrintingRecords;
    if not InRepeatedGroupHeader then true else false;
 
Every Id in the Group should start on a new page
GroupFooter is always empty and isn't really necessary